# Designing a method to return a boolean value

Tags: java, function, methods

I have encountered this problem and don't how to solve it.

Complete the following method for determining ifthe parameter contains ONLY the following lower-case characters: d, r, m, f, s, 1 , t. If yes, return true; otherwise, return false.
If the parameter is `null` or is an empty String, also return `true`.

```
public boolean isSonqStrinq(Strinq s){
```

I have tried the following, but fail:

```
public boolean isSongString (String s){
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    char a = s.charAt(i);
    while (i < s.length()){
    {
        if(a == 'd' | a == 'r' | a == 'm' | a == 'f' | a == 's' | a == 'l' | a == 't')
            j++;
        else
            break;
    }
    i++;
    }
    if (j == s.length())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where do I get wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the first char every time, you need to move `char a = s.charAt(i);` inside the while loop.

Also, you can use a for loop here, remove the j counter, and shorten the return statement like so:

```
public boolean isSongString (String s){
    if(s == null) return true;

    char[] allowedChars = new char[] {'d','r','m','f','s','l','t'};

    for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(Arrays.asList(allowedChars).contains(s.charAt(i)))
            continue;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:

JoD.'s answer is best, it allows the solution to be reduced to a single statement:

```
public boolean isSongString (String s){
    return ((s == null) ||
            (s.matches("^[drmfslt]*$")));
}
```

Comment: This will crash if `s == null`. The OP states that it should return true if `s == null` :-) 
And your code won't compile :-)
`char [] allowedChars = new char[] {'d', 'r', 'm', 'f', 's', 'l', 't'};` should  fix it.

Comment: @ChristofferPasser woops :o fixed now!

Comment: You got it! - `(s.length() == 0)` is better to write simply as [`s.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--).

Comment: Don't even need to check for empty, your regex returns true on an empty string. http://ideone.com/Pc2w1H

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an exercise, I think it is better to only provide some good clues. The fun of discovery is better than an all-out spoiler.

1. Within `while (i < s.length())` the condition is always true, and your `while` loop runs forever.
2. `char a = s.charAt(i)` is executed only once, and contains during the whole program execution only the second character of your string.
3. And why if the exercise states "If the parameter is null or is an empty String, also return true.", would you not try to do that first thing before everything else? That is 50 % of your code completed in 10 secs.
4. Validating strings is done the easiest with [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) has a particularly interesting method for doing that. Spoiler alert: `"^[drmfslt]*$"` - no that is not me cussing you in another language :-D

Answer (score 0):

you should intialize i to 0 and and a to ' ' and in while first statement should be

```
a = s.charAt(i)
```

this should work fine. If not you can comment back.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isSongString (String s){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < s.length()-1){

        char a = s.charAt(i);
        if(a == 'd' | a == 'r' | a == 'm' | a == 'f' | a == 's' | a == 'l' | a == 't')
            j++;
        else
            break;

    i++;
    }
    if (j == s.length())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
public class StringTest {

static boolean test(String n){
    int l=n.length();
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        if(n.charAt(i)!='d'&&n.charAt(i)!='r'&&n.charAt(i)!='m'&&n.charAt(i)!='f'&&n.charAt(i)!='s'&&n.charAt(i)!='1'&&n.charAt(i)!='t'&&n.charAt(i)!=' ')
            return false;

    return true;
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    boolean n=test("RAHUL");
    System.out.println(n);
    n=test("drmfs1t");
    System.out.println(n);
    n=test(" ");
    System.out.println(n);
    n=test("");
    System.out.println(n);
}
}
```

Output:
false
true
true
true

Comment: You don't want to call charAt 8 every loop iteration, this will slow things down significantly